# history.pushState will not work

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is my JS. I am just running this code locally on my machine and I cannot get the URL to change. Is there anything wrong with this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('#content').load('content/index.html'); 

      $('ul#nav li a').click(function(e) {

        href = $(this).attr("href");

        $('#content').load('content/' + href + '.html');

        history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: generally the first argument of the state is an object, but it's still working for me with a string. I would pause inside the event listener to see if every thing is executing correctly.. And you should make the href local by using `var href` otherwise it will be global and open to bugs from elsewhere in the codebase

Comment: @Cristien Updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Declare `href` locally, like `const href = $(this).attr("href");` or `var href = $(this).attr("href");`
2. Set the first argument of the `history.pushState` to an `{}` instead of a `""`,
3. Check if `$("ul#nav li a").attr("href")` is a valid URI **string**: `console.log($("ul#nav li a"), typeof $("ul#nav li a").attr("href") === "string");`

+

## Your problem

You've got a `SecurityError` when you've executed the code with resources on the local file system.

### The reason why this happens

You're executing your code on the local file system(`file:///`). It makes `SecurityError`s because of the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

### [Same-origin policy for `file:` URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

It seems there is no specification for this; *implementation(browser)-defined*. **Chrome** has the strongest policy for this. The second strongest is **Firefox**, the third is **Opera**.

### The solution

You have to **put them all to your web server** and run it on the server, or, [set `allow-file-access-from-files` flag option in **Google Chrome**](http://chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/), [`security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` setting for **FireFox**](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy).

Comment: haha you musta caught my edit before I deleted it. Thank you for your quick response this is the answer! CORS was my culprit all along. Why doesn't it allow me to use file:/// even if I write the entire URL including file:;/// ? Seems fairly straightforward. @K. _

Comment: @Cristien I'm sorry for my late response. I've edited my answer again. :)