# Why history.pushState not working?

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate

I'm using the following code to change the URL of a page without reloading the whole page:

```
 alert( window.location.href ); 
 window.history.pushState( {} , 'foo', '/foo' );
 alert( window.location.href );
```

Result:

**First alert**:

```
file:///C:/Users/name/Desktop/html/first.html
```

**Second alert**:
No Alert and no change in URL but I was expecting following:

```
file:///C:/Users/name/Desktop/html/foo
```

Where's the glitch? And how to change the browser URL without reloading the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [history.pushState will not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814218/history-pushstate-will-not-work)

Answer (score 2):

Don't run this command using the physical files. It should be hosted on a real domain or localhost.

Examples:

http://localhost/first.html

http://www.example.com/first.html