# pushState results in "cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'"

Tags: javascript, html, history.js

I am trying to push a state to the browser history, when clicking the text in the following div element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick="onNavigate('/tester')">link</div>
<script>const onNavigate = path => history.pushState("","", window.location.pathname + path)</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an

> Uncaught DOMException error: Failed to execute
> 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file://[path-to-file]/index.html/tester' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file://[path-to-file]/index.html'.' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file://[path-to-file]/index.html'.

There are plenty similar posts related to `pushState()` and `replaceState()` - like this one [History pushState throws Uncaught DOMException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499337/history-pushstate-throws-uncaught-domexception) but none of them provide a working solution.
I have also tried with `location.href` instead of `location.pathname` without success.
What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the code with an URL starting with http or https? Could be a problem with file.

Comment: nope - and I would really like to have this working both locally without backend. Bonus if it works also on a webserver

Comment: Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/5gkf4x1z/ It's perhaps not allowed for security reasons with `file://`

Comment: Is this Firefox your using, as the origin of `file://` is null in Firefox,.  Have you tried in Chrome.?

Comment: tried in Chrome (Version 90.0.4430.212) and Safari (the error message is slightly different in Safari - but same problem)

Comment: _"I would really like to have this working both locally"_ Then create a local server, as a developer, this will help you tons. There are many tools and many ways to do it

Comment: @blex I need it to work without server. I do have a server test environment, but no-go in this case

Comment: That's not possible for security reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814218/history-pushstate-will-not-work

Comment: If you don't want a server then you can use something like ->  https://www.electronjs.org/   this is what VS Code uses,  it's basically a browser attached to a NodeJS backend.   I assume with this you can then alter origin security settings to allow pushState on `file://` urls.

Comment: That answers it. Thanks @jabaa